# Ajax autocomplete doesn't work with looping result data

Tags: ajax, laravel, autocomplete

I have an edit page in laravel where there is multiple data product that using foreach to display, and i want to autocomplete the name of product using ajax but it doesn't work. but i dont get any error messages.

here is the code

```
@foreach($product as $item){
               <input type="text" name="product" id="product" value="{{ $item->name }}"/>
               <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" value="{{ $item->quantity }}"/>
               <input type="number" name="price" id="price" value="{{ $item->price }}"/>
}
```

and the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#product').autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response){
                console.log(request.term)
                $.ajax({
                    url:"{{ route('autocompleteproduct')}}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        search: request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        response(data);
                    },error:function(){
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function(event, ui){
                $('#product').val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: ID's on divs should be unique, Here you are looping over items spamming the the id of "#product" on each one. use a class, or be more specific with each products actual id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my Comment, ID's on divs should be unique, Here you are looping over items spamming the the id of "#product" on each one. use a class, or be more specific with each products actual id

below I have removed the IDs off each input as you are not using any labels they are not required. I have also wrapped them in a class to loop over each one so we can target the children specifically

```
@foreach($product as $item)
    <div class="product-inputs" id="product-{{ $item->id }}">
        <input type="text" name="product" value="{{ $item->name }}">
        <input type="number" name="qty" value="{{ $item->quantity }}">
        <input type="number" name="price" value="{{ $item->price }}">
    </div>
@endfor
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.product-inputs').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var input = $('#' + id + ' input[name=product]');
        input.autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response){
                console.log(request.term)
                $.ajax({
                    url:"{{ route('autocompleteproduct')}}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        search: request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        response(data);
                    },error:function(){
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function(event, ui){
                input.val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: is the class should $('.product-inputs') instead $('.product-containers') ?

Comment: Thats correct, updated.

Comment: its not working, then i try console.log. i get this output "jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)"

Comment: I've gone ahead and modified both the dom and the js, i added an ID to the container, we then use this inside the loop to target the input correctly, I used find incorrectly.

Comment: still no result, and its seems my autocomplete is not working inside 'each' loop.